# Table events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

What events can be applied to the table. I use pagination, and in case of transfer to another page, necessary to execute any function. e.g.

```
$(".tableStyle")load(function (){
   alert("it works");
});
```

I need to catch the event of changing the contents of the table, or event of moving to another page.

Comment: do it on click event of button when changing page :)

Comment: I assume you mean `(".tableStyle").load` instead of `(".tableStyle")load` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which events can be applied on a table?

Since a table is a DOM element, [all DOM events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) can be applied.

Comment: Thank you, so much